# $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\int_{0}^{x^2}e^{x+t}\mathrm{dt}$ GRE Practice book GR0568 Q24

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have tried to solve $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\int_{0}^{x^2}e^{x+t}\mathrm{dt}$ by two different ways and I'm getting two answers. Please let me know the mistake:

**Method One**
Let $F(t)$ be the antiderivative of $e^{x+t}$.
Thus $F^{'}(t)=e^{x+t}$

So

\begin{align}
   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{0}^{x^2}e^{x+t}\mathrm{dt} & = \frac{\mathrm{d }}{\mathrm{dx}}(F(x^2)-F(0) \nonumber \\
               & = F^{'}(x^2)\cdot2x  -F^{'}(0) \nonumber  \\
                              & = e^{x+x^2}\cdot2x-e^{x} \nonumber
        \end{align}
But consider the following
**Method Two:**
\begin{align}
 \text{Let } I &=\int_{0}^{x^2}e^{x+t}\mathrm{dt} \\
               &=e^{x}\int_{0}^{x^2}e^{t}\mathrm{dt} \\
               &=e^{x}(e^{x^2}-1)\\
               &=e^{x+x^2}-e^{x}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 \text{Thus } \frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}x} &=(2x+1)e^{x+x^2}-e^{x} \\
            \end{align}

Thank you in advance

Comment: 2nd method is correct, 1st is not.

Comment: Can you please tell me the error I have made with the method one

Comment: method 1: $F$ is not a function of $t$ alone.

Comment: First one you need product rule

Comment: Is the anti derivative of $e^{x+t}$ a function of both $x$ and $t$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this line for method 1 and then proceed with product rule:
$\frac{ d}{ dx }(e^x \int_0^{x^2} e^t dt)$

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 is incorrect. Here's how to fix it. Let
$$
F(t,x)=e^{x+t}
$$
so that
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t,x)=e^{x+t}\text{ and }\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(t,x)=e^{x+t}.
$$
Then,
$$
\int_{0}^{x^{2}}e^{x+t}dt=F(x^{2},x)-F(0,x)
$$
and hence
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\int_{0}^{x^{2}}e^{x+t}dt\right] & =\frac{d}{dx}\left[F(x^{2},x)-F(0,x)\right]\\
 & =2x\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(x^{2},x)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x^{2},x)-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,x)\\
 & =2xe^{x^{2}+x}+e^{x^{2}+x}-e^{x}\\
 & =e^{x}\left(\left(2x+1\right)e^{x^{2}}-1\right)
\end{align*}
which agrees with Method 2.